# Java Spring Boot - use dropdown selection as variable

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a dropdown which consists of options retrieved from a method. The user should be able to select one of these options, and press a submit button. Upon pressing the submit button, the button executes a method that takes the selected option and stores it in some other variable.

My drop-down form looks like this currenty:

```
sb.append("<p>"
                + "<div style='height:200px;width:500px;border:1px solid #ccc;font:16px/26px Georgia, Garamond, Serif;overflow:auto;'>"

                + "<form action='/Teacher' method='get'>"

                + "<input type='submit' value='Submit' action='/sendTest' method='post'>"

                + "<input type='submit' value='Reset' action='/resetCurrentTest' method='post'>"

                + "<a>Current Test for students: " + testcont.getActiveTest() + "</a>"

                + "<fieldset><p>"
                + "<label>Select test</label>"
                + "<select id = 'selection'>"
                + currentTestOptions() // input
                + "</select></p></fieldset>"
                + "</form>"
                + "</div>"
                + "</p>");
```

and the method the

```
"<input type='submit' value='Submit' action='/sendTest' method='post'>"
```

button should execute is:

```
@PostMapping("/sendTest")
    @ResponseBody
    public void sendTest(@RequestParam(value = "selection") HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
                    throws IOException, ServletException{

        for(Test test : testcont.showAllTests()){
            if(test.getName().equals("selection")){
                testcont.SetActiveTest(test);
                System.out.println(testcont.getActiveTest());
            }
        }
    }
```

So currently, the buttons react on the click, and "refreshes" the page. However, the method is not executed, as the field which is supposed to store the "selected" value is not updated.

I basically need the correct mapping for the method to react to the button press. Any ideas? Am I going about this the wrong way?

Answer (score 1):

add 'name' attribute to your `select` field like `name=selection`

and  form action='/Teacher' should be `sendTest` not `Teacher` or `formaction` if you want to override form destination with input

Comment: It gives me this error now:

No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/sendTest] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'

Comment: You use @PostMapping while form method is GET